# Collect data from more than one web application

Tags: 2010, metadata

I have 4 web applications (SharePoint 2010) and each web application contains a site collection or 2.  I want to collect them all into one web application without losing the data in all sites, including metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways to perfom the operations.

If you want to move all site collections into single web app then delete the other web apps.then it is fairly easily.(lets assume you have the Web App A,B,c)

- Detach the content database from Web App A & B( go to `central admin> application Management > Manage Content Database`)
- Attach the Content Databases to Web App C.
- Now you have to update the any customization, Hard coded URLs(because url will be change)

If you want to keep the all web applications and move the content.

- Backup the site collections from each web App(a,B)
- Restore the Site collections to destination Web App(C).